# Is it necessary to follow same package name as it was for so file while using .so file in new Android project

Tags: android, android-ndk

I had created one project using native c++ support. In this project I am passing int value from activity to c++ code and native code returns whether this is prime number or not. This works perfectly, Now I want to create .so file to use in another project. I had google many post but not got answer how to get different .so file for all devices. So I had rename .apk file to .zip and extract it. After that I got one .so file.

Now I want to use this .so file in another project. therefore I had created new project with different name but package name is same. I had created one directory inside src/main and named it as jniLib in this lib I had copied my .so file directory. In my MainActivity I load so file as `static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }`

and call my native method `private native String isPrimeNumber(int number);`. Here everything is perfect. Now I can get result without having actual c++ code.

Now Again I created new project and follow above steps which was followed by creating second project, but difference is that now I had changed package name of my application. when I run application my application got crashed with error as

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.app.androidkt.differentpackage, PID: 16970
                                                                                java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String com.app.androidkt.differentpackage.MainActivity.isPrimeNumber(int) (tried Java_com_app_androidkt_differentpackage_MainActivity_isPrimeNumber and Java_com_app_androidkt_differentpackage_MainActivity_isPrimeNumber__I)
                                                                                    at com.app.androidkt.differentpackage.MainActivity.isPrimeNumber(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.app.androidkt.differentpackage.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:10)
                                                                                    at com.app.androidkt.differentpackage.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:38)
                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5268)
                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21550)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:822)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5811)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:681)
```

So my question  are  - 1) Is it necessary to use same package name to use .so file in our application as that of .so file.
2) How I can get different .so file directory  - currently for time being I had extracted it from apk.
3) To use of .so file is to hide the native code only or there is any other purpose also there?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application package name may be anything, but the Java class that consumes native methods implemented in `libnative-lib.so` must be exactly the same as intended by the authors of this `libnative-lib.so` file.

The easiest workaround for your setup is to move your **com.app.androidkt.differentpackage.MainActivity** class to the  [**com.app.androidkt.samplendk**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509856/create-so-file-in-android-studio-and-used-it-in-another-application-in-android) package. Android Studio will help you with this refactoring. Note that now you must declare the full path for MainActivity in your **AndroidManifest.xml**.

Alternatively, you can create a small **com.app.androidkt.samplendk.MainActivity**
 class:

```
package com.app.androidkt.oldpackage;

public class MainActivity {
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
  }
  public native String isPrimeNumber(int number);
}
```

and add few lines to your **MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.app.androidkt.differentpackage;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private com.app.androidkt.oldpackage.MainActivity pmSolver;
  private String isPrimeNumber(int number) {
    return pmSolver.isPrimeNumber(number);
  }
  …
}
```

If you don't know the exact package name used for this `libnative-lib.so`, you can find it by parsing its ELF headers: you will see an exported function named similar to `Java_com_app_androidkt_ samplendk_MainActivity_isPrimeNumber`.

---

**Nitpicker's corner**: it is possible to build a JNI library that will hide its designated class name(s), but it is hard to reliably prevent reverse engineering these names; it is also possible to build a JNI library that will seamlessly connect to different packages.

Comment: Thanks for response. Do you have any idea about how to create .so file from Android Studio. Actually I had asked this question also in separate thread on stack overflow before some time.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Is it necessary to use same package name to use .so file in our
>   application as that of .so file

No, you can use any package name you desire

> 2) How I can get different .so file directory - currently for time
>   being I had extracted it from apk

Copy all .so files to your new project folder: src/main/jniLibs/armeabi

> 3) To use of .so file is to hide the native code only or there is any
>   other purpose also there?

.so file is a library. Hence the purpose is to be convenient in reusing implemented features in multiple projects.

Comment: Thanks for response. 1) When I am using different package name application getting crashed as I said in my question. 2) I don't know how to create different .so file I got only one for time being after extracting apk so how to copy all .so file.

Comment: in order to call C/C++ api from Java, you have to use JNI wrapper. Your Android.mk should point out exactly which library it should compile to : .so or .a by using: include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY) or include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

Comment: I am using Android 3.0.1 there is no Android.mk file is present. Will you please tell me whether I have to add this file. Because I read somewhere Android.mk is used old days.